Is there an easy way to add a dynamic Heading to Next.JS layout in app router?
I'm building an app that will have 3 pages with very similar structure: each of them would have an h1 then the content. I started by adding the h1 to each page and adding the margin-bottom to the h1, but it's repetitive. I would like instead to move this logic into the root's layout.tsx , however, unfortunately I cannot find any way to do this simply. Since it's a server component, accessing document.title it's excluded (the heading would be the same as the title), and the page.tsx cannot communicate with the layout.tsx, as NextJS is adding the page as a children node to the layout. Current what I did is that I created a HOC and I wrap each page with it:
import React from 'react';

export function withPageHeading<P extends object>(Page: React.ComponentType<P>, title: string) {
    const PageWithHeading = (props: P) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className='mb-6'>{title}</h1>
                <Page {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    };

    PageWithHeading.displayName = Page.displayName || Page.name || 'PageComponent';

    return PageWithHeading;
};

export default withPageHeading;

and then the page component:
export const metadata = {
    title: 'Transactions',
}

const Transactions = () => {
    const { transactions } = data;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="bg-white w-full p-8 rounded-xl">
                <TransactionsTable transactions={transactions} />
            </div>
        </div >
    );
};

export default withPageHeading(Transactions, metadata.title);

Is there a better solution for this?
In case I can stick with this one, please let me know if the typing of the props is correct.
